# Scrapy crawls first page, does not follow other links

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Im working on a scrapy that crawls this website :

Page 1: http://www.randstad.nl/mwp2/faces/baanZoeken?pagina=1&filters=vakgebied!5626

Subpage 1 example (from page 1) : http://www.randstad.nl/mwp2/faces/baanDetails?aanvraagnummer=1177658&_adf.ctrl-state=16ovo4scmu_4&sc=0&_afrLoop=15790145645866794

Page 2 : http://www.randstad.nl/mwp2/faces/baanDetails?aanvraagnummer=1509606&_adf.ctrl-state=16ovo4scmu_4&sc=0&_afrLoop=15790170887272918

So what (i think) goes wrong is it gets all the links from page 1, goes to the sub pages (so it goes to the links it extracted, "subpages") and then goes to page 2 and do it again, but i think that after page 1 it only get the first link (instead of all links of page 2) and then continue to page 3 and do the same.

I tried a lot of different code and i still can't get it right, i hope you can have a look at my code and help me out what i do wrong

**Code Spider**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from craig.items import CraigItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import re 

class CraigSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craig_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["randstad.nl"]
    start_urls = ( 
        "http://www.randstad.nl/mwp2/faces/baanZoeken?pagina=1&filters=vakgebied!5626",
        "http://www.randstad.nl/mwp2/faces/baanZoeken?"
        )  
    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("filters=vakgebied!5626", "pagina=")), callback="parse", follow= True),
    ) 

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        #Haalt alle links op
        for link in sel.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'outer-read-more-link')]/@href").extract():
            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse)


        #Gaat alle links af en haalt alle text op
        text_list = sel.xpath('//div[@id="basePage:page:twoColumn:r2:0:functieOmschrijvingPanel::content"]/text()').extract()
        title_list = sel.xpath('//div[@id="basePage:page:panelTitleHeader"]//td[@class="af_panelBox_header-text"]//h1[@class="af_panelBox_header-element"]/text()').extract()
        label_samenvatting = sel.xpath('//div[@id="basePage:page:twoColumn:r1:0:pfl1b"]//table//td//label/text()').extract()
        opleidingniveau_list = sel.xpath('//div[@id="basePage:page:twoColumn:r1:0:pl1"]//ul//li/text()').extract()
        soortbaan_list = sel.xpath('//table[@id="basePage:page:twoColumn:r1:0:soortDienstverbandRNL"]//td[@class="AFContentCell af_panelLabelAndMessage_content-cell"]/text()').extract()
        uren_per_week_list = sel.xpath('//tr[@id="basePage:page:twoColumn:r1:0:it5"]//td[@class="AFPanelFormLayoutContentCell af_panelLabelAndMessage_content-cell"]/text()').extract()
        vakgebied_list = sel.xpath('//tr[@id="basePage:page:twoColumn:r1:0:vakgebieden"]//td[@class="AFPanelFormLayoutContentCell af_panelLabelAndMessage_content-cell"]//li/text()').extract()
        branche_list = sel.xpath('//tr[@id="basePage:page:twoColumn:r1:0:aanvraagBranch"]//td[@class="AFPanelFormLayoutContentCell af_panelLabelAndMessage_content-cell"]/text()').extract()
        datum = sel.xpath('//span[@class="date-changed"]/text()').extract()

        if text_list:
            title = ' '.join(title_list) 
            text = ' '.join(text_list) 
            samenvatting = ' '.join(label_samenvatting)
            opleidingniveau = ' '.join(opleidingniveau_list)
            soortbaan = ' '.join(soortbaan_list)
            urenperweek = ' '.join(uren_per_week_list)
            vakgebied = ' '.join(vakgebied_list)
            branche = ' '.join(branche_list)

            item = CraigItem()
            item['link'] = response.url
            item['title'] = title
            item['text'] = text
            item['samenvatting'] = samenvatting
            item['opleidingniveau'] = opleidingniveau
            item['soortbaan'] = soortbaan
            item['urenperweek'] = urenperweek
            item['vakgebied'] = vakgebied
            item['branche'] = branche
            item['date'] = datum

            yield item
```

**Code Items**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class CraigItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    text = Field()
    link = Field()
    site = Field()
    date = Field()
    samenvatting = Field()
    opleidingniveau = Field()
    soortbaan = Field()
    urenperweek = Field()
    vakgebied = Field()
    branche = Field()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use CrawlSpider when you need following links, but not BaseSpider.

```
  
    class CraigSpider(CrawlSpider):
```

Comment: This made my crawler get more results, but still not all.